# Symfony2 config load order

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

I was wondering what order does Symfony use when loading config files, and I can't seem to find the answer. The config is later flattened using processConfiguration method from Extension class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Symfony loads `app/config/config.yml` first;
- `config_{environment}.yml` afterwards for it to be able to overwrite default settings;
- afterwards all bundle configuration is loaded in the order of the bundles being registered in `app/AppKernel.php`.

Comment: In Symfony 2.3, it seems bundle configs are loaded first, in the order defined, followed by the file specified in `AppKernel::registerContainerConfiguration()`.

Comment: Sorry, but Symfony loads `config_{environment}.yml` first. Usually this file `import`s `config.yml`. This is done by AppKernel.php, at least in a freshly generated project.